# Missing debug buttons on toolbar VS

Tags: visual-studio

On VS 19 when debugging, there used to be the different types of buttons on the toolbar i.e. start, stop, step into, step over, etc. Now for some reason it disappears and when I debug the only thing I see on the toolbar is a play button that shows continue. When I want to do other options, I have to go to the debug tab. Is there a way to restore those standard debug options that would automatically show up on the toolbar on debug mode?

[image]

Here I am debugging but the debug options are missing:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to click on the little dropdown arrow to the right of the toolbar

[image]

which gives you **Add or Remove Buttons**, which you can hover over and select the buttons you need.

[image]

You can also

1. Select **View | Toolbars | Customize...** from the main menu
2. Click on the **Commands** tab
3. Select the **Toolbar:** radio button and choose the **Debug** entry in the dropdown to the right. Looks like this:

[image]

Comment: You are the best!! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Go to Views>Toolbars: Standard and gg it will appear the Debugging in dropdown list.